# What are the ways in which we can cascade data to multiple catalogs?

Tags: sql-server-2005, cascade

I have 10 SQL Servers. On every server there is a catalog MASTER_DATA. This catalog has a table called Employees. Whenever there are changes in the employee info it gets updated on the CENTRAL server in the MASTER_DATA catalog.

Now what I have to do is to cascade the changes in the Employees table to all the MASTER_DATA catalogs on all servers. After this, the same changes needs to be cascaded to all the other catalogs (other then the MASTER_DATA catalog) on all the servers.

I have the following options to do this

1. SSIS Packages
2. Replication
3. Plain Old TSQL Queries

What would be the best way to do this? Also, are there any other ways to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you have provided, and assuming that by "catalog" you mean "database", this seems like an ideal use-case for [transactional replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Your CENTRAL.MASTER_DATA database would be the publisher; all the other databases would be subscribers.

It's not clear from your description why the second tier of duplication is required - i.e. why each non-MASTER_DATA database requires its own copy of the `Employees` table - is there a reason not to have queries refer to the local MASTER_DATA copy of the data? You could use a [synonym](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) in the non-MASTER_DATA databases to avoid having to change your queries.

Comment: The synonym sounds like a better way, however, the current architecture which i have discussed above has been implemented a long time back to improve performance of high usage catalogs.